# Formula to bracket energy use every 10 degrees

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a graph that sums how many heating degree hours are used every 10 degrees:

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

I tried using `SUMIF()`, but I could only get it to work with one criteria. I'm aware of `Index()`, `Match()` and `Vlookup()` but I'm not sure how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

use `=FLOOR(a1,10)` for your degree cells (here a1) to limit them to every multiple of 10